# Display HTML elements with MaterializeCSS via ReactJS

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, materialize

I'm trying to display HTML elements with ReactJS. These HTML elements use *MaterializeCSS*. When I load the elements separately in 'regular' HTML, in my index.html file, all the elements load properly.

Here's my code:

**index.js**

```
const mainpage_buttons = (
      <div classname="side-options">
        <a classname="btn-floating btn-large red" data-activates="slide-out">
          <i classname="material-icons">menu</i>
        </a>
      </div>
);

const mainpage_sidenav = (
      <ul id="slide-out" className="side-nav">
        <li><a className="subheader">Active Surveys</a></li>
        <li><a href="#!">Survey 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#!">Survey 3</a></li>
        <li><div className="divider" /></li>
        <li><a className="subheader">Inacitve Surveys</a></li>
        <li><a href="#!">Survey 1</a></li>
        <li><div className="divider" /></li>
        <li><a className="waves-effect" href="#!"><i className="material-icons">add</i>Create new survey</a></li>
        <li><a className="waves-effect" href="#!"><i className="material-icons">settings</i>Options</a></li>
        <li><a className="waves-effect" href="#!"><i className="material-icons">chat</i>Support</a></li>
      </ul>
  );


React.render(
  mainpage_buttons,
  document.getElementById('menu')
);
React.render(
  mainpage_sidenav,
  document.getElementById('sidebar')
);

//Query for NavBar
$('.btn-floating').sideNav({
      menuWidth: 300, // Default is 240
      edge: 'left', // Choose the horizontal origin
      closeOnClick: true 
    }
);
```

**index.html**

```
<div id = "menu"></div>
<div id = "sidebar"></div>
```

All it does is display a blank screen.

Most people with similar issues only had to change the `class` attribute to `className`. I put my HTML syntax through [this](http://magic.reactjs.net/htmltojsx.htm) converter, so that's certainly not the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is absolutely with an incorrect variable name for `className`.  Half of them in your code are `classname` instead of `className`.  Correct capitalization fixes the problem.